# Unexpected exception on any build in Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I got build errors on any build/any project in Visual Studio Community 2015, after an reinstall.

Build errors are:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TestConsoleApp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets(56,5): error MSB3883: Unexpected exception: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets(56,5): error : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets(56,5): error : at System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed..ctor()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets(56,5): error : --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets(56,5): error : at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets(56,5): error : at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets(56,5): error : at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(String name, Object[] args)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets(56,5): error : at System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets(56,5): error : at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.DesktopBuildClient.GetBasePipeName(String compilerExeDirectory)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets(56,5): error : at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.DesktopBuildClient.GetPipeNameForPath(String compilerExeDirectory)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets(56,5): error : at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.DesktopBuildClient.RunServerCompilation(RequestLanguage language, List`1 arguments, BuildPaths buildPaths, String keepAlive, String libEnvVariable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets(56,5): error : at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.ManagedCompiler.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I got this build error with WinForm, Console and other project types.

When i load any solution, i got the error "The VSPackage package did not load correctly.". If i create a new solution, i also can't build.

[image: The VSPackage package did not load correctly msgbox]

I check the xml file but no clue on how to solved this issue.

[ActivityLog.xml errors (full file on pastbin)](http://pastebin.com/W1TY6fNi)

I reinstall Visual Studio and also create an basic hello console also to troubleshoot.

```
Module ModuleTest

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("hello")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

devenv flags dont make any change

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

> C:\Users\ppolonia>f:
>
> F:>cd F:\Programas (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
>
> F:\Programas (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE>devenv
>   /safemode
>
> F:\Programas (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE>

I'm using Windows 8 64 bits. Bellow is Visual Studio information:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
>   Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01055
>
> Installed Version: Community
>
> Visual Basic 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA322 Microsoft Visual Basic
>   2015
>
> Visual C# 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA322 Microsoft Visual C# 2015
>
> Visual C++ 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA322 Microsoft Visual C++ 2015
>
> Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   5.205.60510.1
>   Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)   14.1.11106.0 ASP.NET and Web
>   Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://www.asp.net/
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.7 Provides common services for use by Azure
>   Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> GitHub.VisualStudio   1.0 A Visual Studio Extension that brings the
>   GitHub Flow into Visual Studio.
>
> Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4 Microsoft Azure Mobile
>   Services Tools
>
> PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2 Microsoft Visual Studio
>   extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive
>   Analytics product.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.60311.1 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> TypeScript   1.8.29.0 TypeScript tools for Visual Studio
>
> Web Essentials 2015.2   2.0.214 Adds many useful features to Visual
>   Studio for web developers. Requires Visual Studio 2015

Bellow is the system information (in Portuguese, my local language):

> Relatório das informações do sistema escritas em: 06/05/16 16:19:58
>   Nome de sistema: MAXTOR8DEVPT [Resumo do sistema]
>
> Item  Valor    Nome do SO Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise   Versão 6.2.9200
>   Compilação 9200    Outra descrição do SO  Indisponível     Fabricante do
>   SO    Microsoft Corporation    Nome do sistema    MAXTOR8DEVPT     Fabricante do
>   sistema   Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.    Modelo do sistema  Z87X-D3H
>   Tipo do sistema   x64-based PC     Sistema SKU    To be filled by O.E.M.
>   Processador   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 3392 Mhz, 4
>   Núcleo(s), 8 Processador(es) Lógico(s)     Data/versão de BIOS    American
>   Megatrends Inc. F7, 02/08/2013     Versão SMBIOS  2.7  Versão do
>   Controlador Incorporado   255.255  Modo de BIOS   Legado   Fabricante da
>   Placa Base    Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.    Modelo da Placa
>   Base  Indisponível     Nome da Placa Base Placa Base   Função da
>   Plataforma    Ambiente de Trabalho     Estado de Arranque Seguro  Não
>   suportado  Configuração PCR7  Indisponível     Diretório do
>   Windows   C:\Windows   Diretório do sistema   C:\Windows\system32 
>   Dispositivo de arranque   \Device\HarddiskVolume1  Região Portugal
>   Camada de abstração de hardware (HAL) Versão = "6.2.9200.16442"    Nome
>   de utilizador Maxtor8DevPT\ppolonia    Fuso horário   Hora padrão de GMT
>   Memória Física (RAM) Instalada    16,0 GB  Memória física total   15,9 GB 
>   Memória física disponível 3,16 GB  Memória virtual total  25,0 GB 
>   Memória virtual disponível    7,48 GB  Espaço de ficheiro de página   9,14
>   GB     Ficheiro de paginação  F:\pagefile.sys  Foi detetado um hipervisor.
>   As funcionalidades necessárias para Hyper-V não serão apresentadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workstation has the FIPS policy enabled in windows which will cause a number of encryption and hashing algorithms to fail if they're used. It's to prevent insecure encryption to be used in Banking and Military environments. Unfortunately it seems that this breaks MsBuild when building Visual Basic (and there are known issues with XAML too).

To solve the issue you need to edit MsBuild.exe.config for the version of MsBuild you're invoking (probably the one in `%Programfiles(x86)%\Msbuild\14.0\bin`).

Add:

```
<configuration> 
    <runtime> 
    ...
        <!-- below tag will disable security policy checking for FIPS -->
        <enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/> 
    ...
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

For [more information on the impact of FIPS, read the KB Article about its effects](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811833).

You may need to do the same thing for devenv.exe.config, which can be found in `%DevEnvDir%` on any Visual Studio command prompt for the version you're having issues with.

Comment: I have FIPS policy enabled by group policy, when i activate the BitLocker on one disk (in the last week).